# How to determine if command line argument have already been decoded?

Tags: perl

I would like to decode `@ARGV` if (and only if) a script was **not** run with `-CA` command line option. For example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Encode qw(decode_utf8);
BEGIN {
    if ( ... ) {    # <--- What condition to put here?
        @ARGV = map { Encode::decode_utf8( $_ ) } @ARGV;
    }
}
```

I have found the variable `${^UNICODE}` in [`perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) and [`perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) but it seems that it's not documented which bit correspond to the `A` flag.

Comment: It says that `${^UNICODE}` reflects the numeric value of the stuff behind `-C` and, above in the table it says that `A` is `32`, so you probably need the 6th bit I guess.

Comment: @simbabque Thanks! I totally missed that part. It seems to work fine (`if ( !(${^UNICODE} & 0x20) ) { .. }`

Comment: `utf8::decode($_) for @ARGV;` (Faster, and doesn't require any modules.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`perlrun` says](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-C-%5B_number%2Flist_%5D*) that the `A` part of the `-C` flag corresponds to `32` (emphasis mine).

> As of 5.8.1, the -C can be followed either by a number or a list of
>   option letters. The letters, **their numeric values**, and effects are as
>   follows; listing the letters is equal to summing the numbers.
>
> ```
> [...]
> A    32   the @ARGV elements are expected to be strings encoded
>           in UTF-8
> ```

Further down it says that `${^UNICODE}` reflects the numeric values of the stuff set behind the `-C` flag. So the correct way to check that `-CA` wasn't used would be `!( ${^UNICODE} & 0x20 )`.